# SELECT DISTINCT in Redshift when using with CTE giving error

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, distinct, common-table-expression

I built a CTE and I am using the 'SELECT DISTINCT' in the subquery. This query fails giving an error. However the query runs successfully when I don't use the distinct command, just SELECT. I am trying to figure why it's failing when using SELECT DISTINCT. Why can't I use select distinct in this situation. This query is auto-generated out of a R package that I am debugging.

**SQL QUERY**

```
with tab as (
  SELECT coh.cohort_definition_id, pr.person_id,
         'ADT' as codeset_tag, pr.procedure_date as drug_exposure_start_date,
         coh.cohort_start_date,
         coh.cohort_end_date
  FROM truven_ccmr_claims_actual_omop.PROCEDURE_OCCURRENCE pr
  JOIN sandbox_truven.PIONEER2023_US_MarketScan_stg coh
      ON pr.person_id = coh.subject_id
  WHERE procedure_concept_id in (
     4012324, 4304921, 4073141, 4071936, 4073142,
     4073143, 2103796, 2109975, 2109976,
     4512827, 4314682, 4286887, 4341536, 4145907) 
  LIMIT 10
)
SELECT distinct * 
FROM tab 
WHERE cohort_end_date >= drug_exposure_start_date
  AND cohort_start_date <= drug_exposure_start_date limit 10;
```

**ERROR**

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
with tab as (SELECT coh.cohort_definition_id, pr.person_id,
         'ADT' as codeset_tag, pr.procedure_date as drug_exposure_start_date,
         coh...

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: failed to find conversion function from
"unknown" to text; [SQL State=XX000, DB Errorcode=500310]
1 statement failed.
```

Comment: Could you please provide what are the datatypes of the columns defined for the following on the tables 
- PR.PersonID
- COH.Subject_ID
- Procedure_Concept_ID
- PR.Procedure_Date
- COH.Cohort_Start/End_Date

Answer (score 0):

For an immediate fix, here is a version which should work:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    cohort_definition_id,
    person_id,
    codeset_tag,
    drug_exposure_start_date,
    cohort_start_date,
    cohort_end_date
FROM tab
WHERE cohort_end_date >= drug_exposure_start_date AND
      cohort_start_date <= drug_exposure_start_date
-- ORDER BY <one or more columns>
LIMIT 10;
```

Redshift doesn't seem to like `SELECT *` mixed with `DISTINCT`, though you should as a matter of best practice list out all columns whose combinations should be distinct.  Also note that using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is fairly meaningless.

Comment: The query I posted works if I use select * instead of select distinct *. I am trying to figure out why select distinct does not work with CTE table.

Comment: Did you read my answer?  You can't do `SELECT DISTINCT *`.  But `SELECT *` or `SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3` is OK.